# Backtrader doesn't display time when backtesting

Tags: backtesting, python, strategy

I am trying to backtest a strategy with [Backtrader](https://www.backtrader.com/) (not the first time) and have a problem while printing date & time for each iteration (time stay on 23:59:59). Here are the first lines of my dataset:

[image: Dataset lines]

What is printed on the console :

[image: Console log]

And finally how I load my data :

```
data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname="BTCUSD_15MIN.csv",
                           datetime=0,
                           fromdate=datetime.datetime(2015,1,13),
                           todate=datetime.datetime(2015,1,15),
                           open=1,
                           high=2,
                           low=3,
                           close=4,
                           openinterest=-1,
                           time=-1,
                           volume=-1,
                           dtformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Has someone already got this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That for sure only solved your problem by chance (because what you chose is smaller than the actual reality)

Your data is obviously `15-minutes` based. But without specification, you let the default values in place: `bt.TimeFrame.Daily`, which gives you the **end of the day** for each bar. No surprises there.

The right choice would therefore be:

```
timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Minutes,
compression=15,
```

This is explained in the *backtrader* community in several posts and in the FAQ.

- FAQ: https://community.backtrader.com/topic/381/faq
- One post with the same content: https://community.backtrader.com/topic/244/backtesting-1-minute-data/

Answer (score 2):

***Answer***: This is the line that sorted out my issue :

```
timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Ticks
```

If interested in the strategy results, it's [here](https://myfinancialmarkets.club/2017/11/23/backtest-a-trading-strategy-in-python/).